# Youtube video cant start playing in webView Android

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I need to display in webView in custom dialog.
Anyway, I can load youtube site, and navigate trought videos, but when I want to play some video and when I click play nothing happens. Video just get orange flash like it is selected, but doesnt start loading and playing. Whats the problem?

I found tutorial on net, and trying to modify it. Here is the code:

```
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    pd = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.web_view_progress_bar);

    webview = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress < 100 && pd.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
            pd.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new YoutubeWebViewClient());
    //shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webview, this.getUrl());
    webview.loadUrl(this.getUrl());

    dialog.show();

}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


private class YoutubeWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Help?

UPDATE:

I've tried this to do in other way, but again problems...

Im trying to embed youtube html5 player in webView. I only get back field without a youtube video. In right corner of webView is the youtube sign, and thats all of it. Dont have android phone, testing app on android x86 platform. is that a problem?

help :) dont care about a way of implementation, i just need this to work ^^

Comment: have you updated your flash player of your phone in which you are testing??.. may be because of  that your not able  to play video.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why but webviewclient class causes the problem , we can run it in default browser remove the webviewclient class and simly load the url of youtube you will be able to run it on 2.2 for 2.1 just use intent and through parse method open it through youtube application

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s")))); }

Comment: im making tv application, and youtube is like a widget. its android 2.2. When i start youtube, i need it to show in somekind of dialog, because video stream is playing in backgroud, and i dont want to start new activity with intents.

Comment: when we take controll from default web browser through webviewclient class  it does not support dynamic content like popup window , here you dont have to actually make a new activity you just have to call the already installed youtube player which is there by default soo by using the intent you call the default player .yes but for showing it in some  kind of dialouge  you need to  create a js dialouge with layouts and from there you will call the youtube embeded link.

Answer (score 0):

this is a kind of bug in android webview as far as i found till now,for me what worked is simply added [Hardware Accleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) permission in manifest.after that video embedded in my webview started playing .

Comment: Hardware Accleration permission does not work on under 2.3 or lower apis. what is yout android:minSdkVersion ? 
So i am using "    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />"